# How to write appwrite.json for dart ? with function that has (execution permission, env variables )

Tags: dart, appwrite

I need an example of appwrite.json that uses dart as run time and has function with execution permission, env variables

I tried appwrite cli to create a env variable but not showing in the appwrite.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like:

```json
{
  "$id": "123asdf",
  "runtime": "dart-2.17",
  // ... other stuff
  "execute": ["users"],
  "variables": {
    "FIRST_VAR": "value",
    "SECOND_VAR": "value"
  }
}
```

For more info, refer to the [appwrite.json docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/command-line-deployment#appwriteJSON).